# Получить AP MAC с Unifi AP без Unifi Controller api

Tags: linux, mac, wifi

Требуется получить MAC адресс Unifi AP, при этом не используя Unifi Controller Api, возможно ли это?

Comment: Точки доступа к которой вы подключаетесь? Это делается стандартными утилитами из shell, или я что-то неправиольно понял?

Comment: @Andy Shevchenko Да, точки к которой я подключаюсь, без использования API контроллера, может у Unifi AP есть свое api? ssh? или же web интерфейс.

Comment: @StanislavShtepam, ну так а `nmap` посканить? Что там открыто.